# Icons in FreshTabbedNavigationContainer tabs bar are giant in IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, freshmvvm

I am trying to show 4 icons for 4 tabs in the bar of my FreshTabbedNavigationContainer using FreshMVVM and Xamarin.Forms of course, they look as they should when I execute the app on an Android emulator, but when I use my Mac and emulate the app on an IOS emulator, these icons become gargantuan, just as you see in this picture.
[image]
Here is my code:
FreshTabbedNavigationContainer Code:

```
private static FreshTabbedNavigationContainer TabbedPageContainer = null;

TabbedPageContainer = new FreshTabbedNavigationContainer(navigation.ToString());
Products = TabbedPageContainer.AddTab<HomeViewModel>(null, "IconHomeInverted.ico", null);
Discover = TabbedPageContainer.AddTab<HomeViewModel>(null, "IconMagnifyingGlassInverted.ico", null);
Account = TabbedPageContainer.AddTab<HomeViewModel>(null, "IconUserInverted.ico", null);
Settings = TabbedPageContainer.AddTab<HomeViewModel>(null, "IconSettingsInverted.ico", null);

#region UI
//Dissables swipe only in android because in IOS can not be done
TabbedPageContainer.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(false);
TabbedPageContainer.BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");
#endregion

page.CoreMethods.SwitchOutRootNavigation(navigation.ToString());
```

My icons are located in "MyProject.IOS", they are not in the resources folder or anything like that.
That is all, if you need more information I will provide it as soon as I see your request. I hope all of you have a great day.

Comment: Is it on VS mac or windows? There are some issues with iOS with latest update of Mac OS and VS Mac.esp GestureRecognizers , https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10162. May be its related..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it, my icons were 500x500 aprox, on Windows, visual studio or fresh MVVM resize the image to fill the tabbed bars; this does not happen on Mac, so they were showing their actual size, I resized them to 38x38 and now they look like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS "Human Interface Guidelines" have suggested sizes for the custom icons in the Navigation Bar.

These sizes go from 24px to 28px for the @1x scale factor meaning that for the other scale factors we will have something like:

**24px**
48px@2x
72px@3x

**28px**
56px@2x
84px@3x

Of course, you are capable of adjusting these numbers to keep consistency across your application.

More information about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/)

Hope this helps.-